# Several tabsheets and pure table

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

i have a general questions about matplotlib.

I have a lot of charts. Would it be possible to split them
and show them on several tabsheets?

Some of the results are pure tables. is there a way to show
table only or do i need all the time a diagramm for?

thanks
melanie

Comment: Of course you can put a table into a figure without any diagram, use `plt.table`. Apart, I don't think this question is clear and specific enough to be answered here. What is a "tabsheet"?

Comment: this is a window control with some tabs at the top to switch between the window.

Comment: There is no built-in option for tabs in matplotlib itself. But matplotlib can be integrated into GUIs like PyQt or Tkinter, such that it is of course possible to show several figures in different tabs.

Comment: ok many thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Well, that wasn't really an answer, because the question itself is not well suited for stackoverflow. I would like to invite you to read [ask] and [mcve]. So I see two options here: (1) You edit the question to be on-topic with a specific problem or (2) you delete it.